# auto finding index-file which is default is not working at edge browser

Tags: url, xampp, microsoft-edge

i have xampp setting and have index.php at root folder

as i wish and default it should point index.php and it worked well before

the problem here, when i type "localhost" automaticly changed to "localhost/login"(there are nothing to show)

and when i type full-name "localhost/index.php" it worked well

honestly 3h ago i tested anther project with xampp and that code says when type "localhost" toss it to "localhost/login"

but there are 2 project which is totally different and even in Chrome it worked well(localhost -> localhost/index.php)

Is there any chance Edge(or the other) can cache url-rool or something?

Comment: problem solved, i delete all Edge-browser-cache and it worked well. anyone can tell me how to close this question without deleting?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding. Please see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved, i delete all Edge-browser-cache and it worked well.